# Would these components work for a Nixie tube power supply?

Tags: power-supply, high-voltage, circuits

recently I have been trying to design a custom nixie tube high voltage power supply. I've come across this youtube video https://youtu.be/kNBPaFiHbt0?t=5m45s, and at 5:45 there is a nice view of the power supply schematic. I've decided to replicate the schematic (hopefully I didn't make any error), on EasyEDA The circuit I've made uses devices (You can find the list in the bottom part of the EasyEDA page I linked) different from the ones used in the video, but from the datasheet I think it might work, but I'm not entirely sure. Can anyone help me?

Also, I don't know if this is a good place to ask for circuit reviews, if it isn't could you recommend any other website?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: That's a terrible schematic! See [Rules and guidelines for drawing good schematics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/28255/11683).

Comment: This seems to be related to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/344999/4512, which got deleted when you deleted your first account.  Changing identities is not how to get around bad rep and history here.  You do that by fixing the bad stuff, not pretending someone else did it.

Comment: Yes, I deleted my account, but I didn't try at all to change identity.Also the question is still there open to the public. Was it necessary to point this out?

Comment: *"Was it necessary to point this out?"*.  Yes.  People have a right to know your history when deciding whether to spend time answering your questions.  For example, I didn't appreciate the way you jerked us around with the first Nixie tube question, so I'm not going to answer this one.  If I hadn't realized you were the same user, I would have appreciated someone else pointing that out.

Comment: I'm really sorry that you tought that the first post was made to waste your time, if there is something I can do to 'fix' my repetutation please tell me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a power supply expert, but long ago I tried building a Nixie supply with a 555 timer. I didn't have good results -- though I'm not claiming it can't be done. But for this kind of power supply, you're probably better off using a dedicated SMPS controller. Sure, there's educational value in designing the whole thing with a 555, but there's also value in using a purpose-built IC, and carefully reading its data sheet.

You need to give careful thought to the particular components you use, especially since you're trying to get to 180V. You want a low-Rds MOSFET, a good fast diode, and a good inductor. If you're choosing parts different than the original spec because it's what you happen to have around, you may have trouble.

Finally, board layout matters. A bad board layout can reduce efficiency and be sensitive to external noise. Not to mention emit noise.

I had good luck for my Nixie project using the design at http://www.desmith.net/NMdS/Electronics/NixiePSU.html. He uses a MAX1771 controller, and gives a thorough circuit description, a bill of materials, and covers how to lay out the board. I used his design and BOM, and laid out a board looking very much like his, and it works well.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the advices, I'll definitelly give the design a look.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you could definitely make a Nixie power supply out of a 555.
But there is a catch, poor regulation .Now there is a load of such circuits on the web.

I would try an SMPS chip like sg3525 or the simpler uc3842.( although I do not have expertise on the latter chip).